# Merging two dataframes based on last date

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes which I would like to merge together based on the ids and the dates

The first dataframe looks like this:

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-30    1417744
  BBB   2021-06-30    3946750
  AAA   2021-07-31    2792182
  BBB   2021-07-31    81073822
```

While the second dataframe looks similar to this:

```
   ID      Date       Day_Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-05    14
  AAA   2021-06-12    11
  AAA   2021-06-21    15
  BBB   2021-06-06    33
  BBB   2021-06-18    35
  BBB   2021-06-27    55
  AAA   2021-07-08    6
  AAA   2021-07-12    8
  BBB   2021-07-15    9
  BBB   2021-07-31    10
```

(Note too that the `Date` column are `String` types)

What I would like to do is merge the two dataframes together such that the last value in the `Date` column for each month and for each `ID` will have the `EoM_Val`, so that the final merge looks like this:

```
   ID      Date       Day_Val    EoM_Val
----------------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-05    14
  AAA   2021-06-12    11
  AAA   2021-06-21    15         1417744
  BBB   2021-06-06    33
  BBB   2021-06-18    35
  BBB   2021-06-27    55         3946750
  AAA   2021-07-08    6
  AAA   2021-07-12    8          2792182
  BBB   2021-07-15    9
  BBB   2021-07-31    10         81073822
```

Unfortunately, I'm having quite a bit of difficulty with it, so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that your first dataframe is named `df1` and you second one, `df2`.

Create a month column for each dataframe:

`df1['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']).dt.month`

Then group both dataframes by `ID` and `Month`, taking the `last` occurrence in each group, *e.g.* for `df2`:

`df2_grouped = df2.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).last()`

This yields:

```
Date    Day_Val
ID  Month       
AAA     6   2021-06-21    15
BBB     6   2021-06-27    55
AAA     7   2021-07-12    8
BBB     7   2021-07-31    10
```

This allows you to identify the rows for which you want the `EoM_value` to be displayed.

You can then merge `df1_grouped` and `df2_grouped` into `df_merged`, which will contain `ID`, `Day_Val` and `EoM_Value`.

Finally, create a `EoM_Val` column in `df2`, and populate it with NaN values. The only thing left to do is to merge this updated `df2` with `df_merged`, using an outer merge to retain all rows in the final dataframe.